# Meteor - collection.find() always returns all fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

Ran into this (slightly annoying problem) I'm trying to look up all records in a collection and not show (or show) a specific field (score). This is just an example and not reflective of my actual code, but the problem is always reproducible. The fields I am excluding are very large and I'm merely trying to generate a menu of available records.

Commands like

```
    players.find({},{score:1})
    players.find({},{score:0})
```

Always return every field, instead of triggering the exclude/include in mongodb. Am I worried about nothing, since the template potentially can control what data gets rendered to html? Still feels like the data is transferred to the client side regardless; and shows up in the console.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong because you assume that Mongo syntax will be applicable directly to Meteor.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

your syntax is off a bit, it should be

```
CollectionName.find({}, {fields: {'onlyThisField':1}});
```

or

```
CollectionName.find({}, {fields: {'everythingButThisField':0}});
```

your template does indeed control what data is displayed, but there are still many scenarios where field limiting makes sense - privacy of data or efficiency (some fields of all records, all fields of the 'current' record) are two common ones

you didnt mention it, but this usually is within a publish function - see http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish - the `fields` modifier is also available on the client, but there it does not limit data sent down to client, just to the template - server side field reduction/selection has different benefits

--

double check that you've removed the `autopublish` package too, however you should see a warning if you have that active and write your own publish functions, which is where you would most commonly use `fields`

Comment: That did not work.. You're missing my point, it doesn't matter how I structure the mongo query, to include one field, or exclude every field; it always returns the same results;every field.

Comment: Are you using this on the client side code? It only works on the server. If you could put the code up it would help a bit more because its very difficult to reproduce it if you've addressed everything like in this answer.

Comment: Is there nothing like this on the client side?

Comment: Client-side you can modify the mongo result set in a handlebar template action/function or event. `CollectionName.find().fetch().filter(function(array,index){return new_array;});`

Comment: Note: Minimongo now supports Client-side use of `fields`. https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find

Comment: Strangely, I ran into the same problem, when using onlyThisField:1 without the single quotes it did not work, but adding single quotes (i.e. 'onlyThisField':1) solved it.

Answer (score 11):

First, if you want to control some fields in `Collection.find()`，you can try to do it this way:

```
CollectionName.find({}, {fields: {field:1}});
```

but it was working only on the server.

Or try this:

On the server:

```
Meteor.publish("myCollection", function () {
    return SvseTree.find({},{fields: {field:1}});
});
```

On the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("myCollection");
```

then run `meteor remove autopublish`.

Second, if you want to  get Array of Collection.find(),  try to do it: 
    Collection.find().fetch();

Comment: So, right now there isn't any way to limit the fields on the client side?