# How to get variable on submit mongodb and meteor

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

So I am working on a wait list type application. When a user submits their information into the list (using autoform) they should be sent a messsage through the Twilio service.

I currently have a hard coded variable working with twilio

Method to send sms

```
Meteor.methods({
sendSMS: function (phoneNumber) {
    var authToken = 'token value here';
    var accountSid = 'sid value here';
    twilio = Twilio(accountSid, authToken);
    twilio.sendSms({
        to: phoneNumber, // Any number Twilio can deliver to
        from: '+18.....', // A number you bought from Twilio and can use for outbound communication
        body: 'You have been added to the waitlist' // body of the SMS message
    }, function (err, responseData) { //this function is executed when a response is received from Twilio
        if (!err) { // "err" is an error received during the request, if any
            // "responseData" is a JavaScript object containing data received from Twilio.
            // A sample response from sending an SMS message is here (click "JSON" to see how the data appears in JavaScript):
            // http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms#example-1
            console.log(responseData.from); // outputs "+14506667788"
            console.log(responseData.body); // outputs "word to your mother."
        }
    });
}
});
```

Here is the event I have working with hard coded number:

```
Template.home.events({
    "submit #student-form": function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var phoneNumber = '+18.....';
        Meteor.call("sendSMS", phoneNumber);
        // alert("You have been added to the WaitList");
        swal("Success!", "You have been added to the WaitList", "success")
    }
});
```

My quickform

```
            {{>quickForm id="student-form" collection="Students" type="insert" template="bootstrap3-horizontal" label-class="col-sm-3" input-col-class="col-sm-9"}}
```

What I want to know is how do I get the phone number value that was just submitted into the mongodb collection so that I can send a message to that specific phone number with twilio?

Comment: Just found this link that solves the problem
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458095/find-value-in-meteor-mongo)

Comment: This should get the value of the textfield:
`var phoneNumber = $('.classOfTextFieldWithPhoneNumber').val();`
not sure how to adapt this for quickform

Answer (score 0):

OP found the answer here: [Find Value in Meteor Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458095/find-value-in-meteor-mongo)

> If you are looking to retrieve a field out of the returned document,
>   you can specify as much using the fields option:
>
> ```
> database.findOne({}, {sort: {'timeStamp' : -1}, limit:1, fields: {'myField': 1, _id: 0})
> ```
>
> That will retrieve an object in format like this:
>
> `{'myField': 'value of myField'}`