# Meteor: Displaying documents separated by Days

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've got a MongoDB where each row has a datetime and a name.

[image: Database]

I want a selection of them, let's say every row since the 9th, but I also want to display them with a seperator for each day like:

```
TODAY:
-First
-Second

IN 3 DAYS
-Third
-Fourth
```

So i figured the code has to be like

```
{{#each day}}
    <h1>{{day}}</h1>
    {{#each entrie}}
        <p>entrie</p>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

But how can I separate the documents in my collection into groups, one for each day?

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by "separate the documents in days"? do you mean visually?

Comment: I want to separate the results by the day into smaller parts of results.

Answer (score 1):

Simple search found this: [Does Meteor have a distinct query for collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514733/does-meteor-have-a-distinct-query-for-collections) and [Meteor - collection.find() always returns all fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961456/meteor-collection-find-always-returns-all-fields)

You can find unique dates from your collection like so:

```
MyCollection.find({}, {fields: {'date': 1}}).distinct('date', true);
```

Then you can specify a function called `days` that returns these specific dates. Then like shown in your example above, you can do something like:

```
{{#each days}}
    {{this}}
    {{#each names}}
       <p>{{this}}</p>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

You would specify names to find names in your collection where the date is the current day (ie. `this.valueOf()`).

Comment: distinct isn't supported anymore. But I think it wouldn't work anyways because the datetimes have different times on each day :/

Comment: Correct, there's `.distinct()` in native mongo but not in meteor. Use underscores `_.uniq()` instead.

Comment: if the field is a datetime, as stated, rather than just a date then this won't work, because most datetime will be distinct already, so you end up with no grouping at all. Besides, we don't want to eliminate anything (remove distinct), but group by date.

Comment: Well you could always use `_.uniq()` and then built a dictionary that maps date (excluding time) to a list of `name`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to group your results by day. You can easily do that using `_.groupBy`. Here is an example that might work:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
   days: function() {
      return _.groupBy(MyCollection.find().fetch(), function(day) {
          return Date(day.datetime).getDay();
      });
   }
});
```

But you will need to update your template, too, to use `this` inside the outer `each` loop:

```
{{#each days}}
    {{#each this}}
       <div>{{name}}</div>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, but hope my answer helps you.

I created a solution on [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/f5h7X9zBok25daD5S/days) so you can play with it to see how it works.

In the `main.html`, the `list` template's data context is set by `{{#each days}}`, which is an array of an array. You iterate through the outer array in this outer `#each` loop. The internal array is a simple 2-element array whose 0th element is a string "today" or "in a day", etc., while the 1st element is again an array containing the objects coming from the database after grouping by the day, and where these object's `item` value is displayed in the internal `{{#each this.[1]}}` loop for each item for a given day.

```
// main.html
<body>
  {{> list}}
</body>

<template name='list'>
    {{#each days}}
        {{this.[0]}}
        {{#each this.[1]}}
            <div>{{item}}</div>
        {{/each}}
        <br>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

The `/client/app.js` returns the `days` data context by mapping, filtering, grouping and mapping again the documents coming from the database using chained `underscore.js` functions. The first `map` sets the time to the beginning of a given day, the `filter` leaves in the outer array only those documents that are after a certain date, then you `group` by the dates, and finally, the second `map` just gives you `today` in place of the default string and leaves the `in a day`, `in 2 days` etc. strings in place.

Also, in the included `moment.js` package, you reset the thresholds for time differences so that you measure time differences in days always instead of the default seconds, minutes, hours, etc.

```
// client/app.js
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('h', 0);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('s', 0);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('m', 0);

Template.list.helpers({
   days: function() {
            var ret =  _.chain(Days.find().fetch())
                            .map(function(day) {
                                 return {_id: day._id, dateTime: moment(day.dateTime).startOf('day')._d, item: day.item};
                            })
                            .filter(function(day) {
                                 return moment(day.dateTime) >= moment([2015,7,5])
                            })
                            .groupBy(function(day) {
                                 return moment(day.dateTime).from([2015, 7, 4]);
                            })
                            .map(function(v, k) {return k === "1 days ago" ? ["today", v] : [k, v]})
            return ret._wrapped;
    }
});
```

/common.js creates the `Days` handle on the database `days` collection.

```
// common.js
Days = new Mongo.Collection("days");
```

And `/server/app.js` just injects a few documents into the database to start with.

```
// server/app.js
Meteor.startup(function () {
  if (Days.find().count() === 0) {
    var entries = [
      {
        dateTime: new Date('2015-08-04 09:01:01'),
        item: "-Zeroth"
      },
      {
        dateTime: new Date('2015-08-05 11:01:01'),
        item: "-First"
      },
      {
        dateTime: new Date('2015-08-05 17:02:11'),
        item: "-Second"
      },
      {
        dateTime: new Date('2015-08-09 12:11:07'), 
        item: "-Third"
      },
      {
        dateTime: new Date('2015-08-09 21:23:18'),
        item: "-Fourth"
      }
    ];
    _.each(entries, function (entry) {
      Days.insert({
        dateTime: entry.dateTime,
        item: entry.item
      });
    });
  }
});
```