# Why call collection.find in an Iron Router controller

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have built a small meteor app based on code generated by the excellent [Meteor Kitchen](http://www.meteorkitchen.com/) project. This code works and renders the collection to the page, but there is one thing I am confused about.

A subset of the code is here:

**router.js**

```
 this.route("articles", {path: "/articles", controller: "ArticlesController"});
```

**ArticlesController**

```
this.ArticlesController = RouteController.extend({
   template: "Articles",

   onBeforeAction: function() {
        this.next();
    },

   action: function(){
      if (this.isReady()) {
         this.render();
      } else {
         this.render("loading");
      }
   },

   isReady: function() {
      var ready = true;
      var subs = [ Meteor.subscribe('allArticles') ];
      _.each(subs, function(sub) {
         if(!sub.ready())
            ready = false;
      });
      return ready;
   },

   data: function() {
      return {
         articles: Articles.find({})
      };
   }
});
```

**server/pubs/articles.js**

```
Meteor.publish('allArticles', function() {
  return Articles.find({});
});


Meteor.publish('singleArticle', function(articleId) {
  check(articleId, String);
  return Articles.find({_id: articleId});
});
```

As I understand how this code is working, the following takes place:

(1) Collection is published via **allArticles** and **singleArticle** subscriptions
(2) ArticlesController subscribes to **allArticles**
(3) **data** function in the ArticlesController extracts the data (from the subscription?) to the **articles** array which is then exposed to the Blaze template.

Where I am confused: 
Why do we need to do a **Articles.find({})** in the data function? Where do we access the **allArticles** data ... it seems we are going back to the **Articles** collection directly and how is that possible if we have subscribed only to **allArticles** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you don't show it, I'm assuming you have the following line in your code, defined somewhere that will execute it on both the server, and the client:

```
  Articles       = new Mongo.Collection('articles');
/*CollectionName = new Mongo.Collection('DBCollectionName');*/
```

[Docs.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection)  When this is executed on the server a Collection is created, and assigned to the variable name Articles.  'articles' is the name used to store this collection in MongoDB.

When this is executed on the client, a mini mongo Collection is created.  It initially will have no documents in it.

Next you have server only code:

```
Meteor.publish('allArticles', function() {
  return Articles.find({});
});

Meteor.publish('singleArticle', function(articleId) {
  check(articleId, String);
  return Articles.find({_id: articleId});
});
```

[Docs.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish)  This defines two publications, 'allArticles' and 'singleArticle'.  These are not Collections themselves, but are rules that specify a set of data that the server will publish, and a client may subscribe to.  While these two publications return data from the Server's Articles collection, publications can return data from one or more collections, or by directly using the underlying ddp protocol you can publish data that comes from another data source (not mongodb).

Next on the client you subscribe to a collection:

```
Meteor.subscribe('allArticles')
```

[Docs.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe)  This call takes the name of a publication defined on the server ('allArticles'), and subscribes to it.  The server then executes the publish function, and sends over ddp the set of data returned.  This data is stored in the Client-side Mini Mongo Collection created above, and named Articles.

Also the server will monitor the Articles collection for changes, and if the resultset of the 'allArticles' publication changes, will send these changes as updates to the client.

So next you have the data function in your Controller (Client side).

```
data: function() {
  return {
     articles: Articles.find({})
  };
}
```

[Docs.](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#rendering-templates-with-data)  This sets the data context for the render function.

The reason this calls Articles.find rather than allArticles.find is because allArticles is not a collection, but was instead the name of the publication the client used to request the server send data, that was stored in the clients mini mongo collection named Articles.

Comment: What an incredible answer. I would vote it up twice if I could. This part makes complete sense to me " stored in the clients mini mongo collection named Articles.".

Answer (score 1):

> Where do we access the allArticles data ... it seems we are going back
>   to the Articles collection directly and how is that possible if we
>   have subscribed only to allArticles ?

You return this as part of your data object so that you can access it in your template.  In your `Articles` template you can now use `{{#each articles}}` directly without a helper function because `articles` is part of your data context.  You can also access the articles returned from your controllers `data` portion inside of your `Articles` template helpers by using `this.articles`.

> Why do we need to do a Articles.find({}) in the data function?

These queries being performed in your controllers data function act on the clients minimongo Articles collection as opposed to the servers. Once the information is published from the server, and the client has subscribed to it, the client has this information available in their minimongo instance, but still needs to access it somehow. Basically, the publication makes the information available, but the `Articles.find({})` accesses it for the client.

Accessing this information inside of the data function of your controller is simply to avoid doing it inside of your template.

I think that your misunderstanding comes from the third step that you have described:

> data function in the ArticlesController extracts the data (from the
>   subscription?) to the articles array which is then exposed to the
>   Blaze template.

The data function extracts the data from minimongo on the client which contains the information from the subscription.  Minimongo lies between the subscription and the data function.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to know more about your app to answer the question. Are you viewing just a single article, or is there a page that lists them all?

If you are viewing a **single** article you would need to subscribe to the `singleArticle` publication.

If you were showing a **list** of articles, you would need to subscribe to `allArticles`.  If there are a lot of articles, you could improve the speed of your app by limiting the number of **fields** with a [query projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961456/meteor-collection-find-always-returns-all-fields).

Comment: I don't think it was the askers intention to ask when to use each publication